# Bower components not found when using Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bower

When I start my node-server at port `8080`, and have a look at in the browser, I see this:

[image]

I doesn't find any of the bower-files.

When I just preview the code through an editor, like brackets. Everything works. I don't understand why `node` would cause a problem.

My last route in node looks like this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

And my includes in the HTML file looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<style>
    html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
    body                    { padding-top:50px; }
    #todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }
</style>

<!-- JS Source -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./core.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to expose the `bower_compoments` directory just as you (probably) did with `public` using `express.static` middleware.

```
var path = require('path')
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')))
```

---

Please note that as of October 2017, you should [migrate away from Bower](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/).

Comment: Thank you so much! Bower doesnt explain this on their website!

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the public folder. Preferably with `.bowerrc`. Create a file with name `.bowerrc` in the same directory as `bower.json` with following content:

```
{
  "directory": "public/bower_components"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you are using the `express` package to create your server's routes.
Have you setup static assets? http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html